# Mocha running slow. Takes as long as 8s to perform the complete test suite

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mocha.js

I am using Mocha with mongoose. The tests are running very slow and take a long time to execute, sometimes as long as 8s. I am connected to a local mongo database on my system.
The relevant files are as follows:

**test_helper.js**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//before executed only once for the entire test suite
before((done)=>{
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:20000/users_test');
  mongoose.connection
  .once('open',()=> {done();})
  .on('error',(error)=>{
    console.warn('Warning',error);
  });
});



//define a hook - a function that gets executed before any test runs

beforeEach((done)=>{
  mongoose.connection.collections.users.drop(()=>{
    //ready to run the next test!
    done();
  });
});
```

**user.js file**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name:String,
  postCount:Number

});

const User = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

the tests are spread across several files. I have uploaded the files on drive and the links are:
update_test.js - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fHO8gLrRE3QsRfRfbwbpOOEg0zcGGxPL

reading_test.js - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Kck1GS8j07MCQyYf0a1xpiGJ3lvvowLF

delete_test.js - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KLt61139ey4BXg0HC9p8V3_Q5fH0UP39

create_test.js - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AN2d2gq70UnNky5_4GQ6_fKlxj28WEA-

Comment: `8` seconds per test or all tests?

Comment: all the tests combined take that time

Comment: I don't think that is a big time frame.

Comment: it's quite big when i compare it with the tutorial which i am following, in which it takes less than 300ms